# Resource for Chess Problems about particular topics

Tags: problems

Most puzzles I find are where payout is relatively high. e.g mate in 2-3 moves, play right and get a piece etc. However, I needed a resource which gives me some puzzles/exercises about particular topics in chess where payout is not that high. For example puzzles focussing solely on whether to exchange a piece in a given situation or not. Or whether to be aggressive or defensive in a given scenario. Chesstemp does have tactics tags in its puzzles but I was not able to work out how to get puzzles solely with a few selected tags. Thank you for your kind help

Comment: See [Daily strategy training](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/22857/daily-strategy-traing/22860) for a similar question.

Comment: I believe the paid version of chesstempo allows to search for tags.

Comment: Thank you itub. Just understood the difference between tactics and strategy courtesy your link. Yes I am looking for more strategy puzzles rather than tactical ones which are available by truckload. Will go through Roots of Positional Understanding as you suggested there.

Comment: Not sure if it's on-topic to ask for resource opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Dvoretsky's books are full of what you seek.  Just search him on amazon.